# Key error on pandas merge, but both dataframes contain the key

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, census

I'm trying to work with US Census data using the census package.
I'm doing API requests through the census package like this:

```
req = c.acs.state_county_tract(tuple(allowed_vars), states.CA.fips, '013', '313102')
```

Then converting to pandas data frames and trying to merge the frames:

```
row_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(req)
```

These are the column names for two of the data frames I'm trying to merge:

```
['B01001_001E', 'B01002_001E', 'B01003_001E', 'B02001_001E', 'B02008_001E', 'B02009_001E', 'B02010_001E', 'B02011_001E', 'B02012_001E', 'B02013_001E', 'B02014_001E', 'B02015_001E', 'B02016_001E', 'B02017_001E', 'B02018_001E', 'B02019_001E', 'B03001_001E', 'B03002_001E', 'B03003_001E', 'B04004_001E', 'state', 'county', 'tract']


['B04005_001E', 'B04006_001E', 'B04007_001E', 'B05001_001E', 'B05002_001E', 'B05003_001E', 'B05004_001E', 'B05005_001E', 'B05006_001E', 'B05007_001E', 'B05008_001E', 'B05009_001E', 'B05010_001E', 'B05011_001E', 'B05012_001E', 'B05013_001E', 'B05014_001E', 'B05015_001E', 'B06001_001E', 'B06002_001E', 'state', 'county', 'tract']
```

You can see that both frames contain the 'state', 'county', and 'tract' keys.
When I try to merge the frames:

```
row_df = row_df.merge(second_df, on = ["state","county","tract"], how = 'left')
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'state'
```

To give you more info, here is an example of one of the data frames and the dtype of its columns:

```
B07203_001E B07204_001E B07401_001E B07402_001E B07403_001E B07407_001E B07408_001E B07409_001E B07410_001E B07411_001E ... B08007_001E B08008_001E B08009_001E B08011_001E B08012_001E B08013_001E B08014_001E state   county  tract
0   0.0 4280.0  None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    ... 2077.0  2077.0  2077.0  1980.0  1980.0  99815.0 2077.0  06  013 313102
1 rows × 23 columns
```

```
B07203_001E    float64
B07204_001E    float64
B07401_001E     object
B07402_001E     object
B07403_001E     object
B07407_001E     object
B07408_001E     object
B07409_001E     object
B07410_001E     object
B07411_001E     object
B07412_001E     object
B07413_001E     object
B08006_001E    float64
B08007_001E    float64
B08008_001E    float64
B08009_001E    float64
B08011_001E    float64
B08012_001E    float64
B08013_001E    float64
B08014_001E    float64
state           object
county          object
tract           object
```

Why is this happening? I'm really pulling out my hair here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you have any reference for API...So that I can also pull it & apply your logic accordingly

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/census/ for the python package. And here's where you can get an API guide from the Census Bureau:   https://www.census.gov/data/developers/guidance/api-user-guide.html.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error:

> KeyError 'state'

It happens only if I have the following situation:

- The columns of the dataframe that you are reporting, are actually the **values** of the rows of the dataframe
- The merge fails because the **on** key argument is referring to a column that is not there

More information can be found in the documentation:

**merge():** https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html

**However, here is what worked for me:**

When I run the code this way, by assigning a list of values to a dataframe, the merge works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate random 23 values for the df
data = [np.random.rand(23)]

# first df column names
row_df_cols = ['B01001_001E', 'B01002_001E', 'B01003_001E', 'B02001_001E', 'B02008_001E', 'B02009_001E', 'B02010_001E', 'B02011_001E', 'B02012_001E', 'B02013_001E', 'B02014_001E', 'B02015_001E', 'B02016_001E', 'B02017_001E', 'B02018_001E', 'B02019_001E', 'B03001_001E', 'B03002_001E', 'B03003_001E', 'B04004_001E', 'state', 'county', 'tract']

# create row_df
row_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=row_df_cols)

# second df column names
second_df_cols = ['B04005_001E', 'B04006_001E', 'B04007_001E', 'B05001_001E', 'B05002_001E', 'B05003_001E', 'B05004_001E', 'B05005_001E', 'B05006_001E', 'B05007_001E', 'B05008_001E', 'B05009_001E', 'B05010_001E', 'B05011_001E', 'B05012_001E', 'B05013_001E', 'B05014_001E', 'B05015_001E', 'B06001_001E', 'B06002_001E', 'state', 'county', 'tract']                 

# create second_df
second_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=second_df_cols)

# merging
row_df = row_df.merge(second_df, on = ["state","county","tract"], how = 'left')

print(row_df)
```

Here is the output:

```
       B01001_001E  B01002_001E  B01003_001E  B02001_001E  B02008_001E  B02009_001E  ...  B05012_001E  B05013_001E  B05014_001E  B05015_001E  B06001_001E  B06002_001E
0     0.483652     0.867077     0.868199     0.026156     0.486646     0.674776  ...     0.194051     0.979108     0.309233      0.44728     0.322487     0.049854
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrea. My dataframes have a mixture of data types and contain None values. I've edited my post to show an example.

Comment: Hello Crawdad_Buckwheat,

could you please give an example with data of row_df and second_df.

I tried again to reproduce your error, but I can't, the merge works.